# Pandas to_datetime specifying format for iso 8601 timestamp string with nanoseconds

Tags: python, pandas, iso8601, strftime

I have ISO 8601 formatted timestamp strings in a column of a Pandas dataframe. I am looking for the most efficient way to convert this column of strings to Pandas datatime objects. pd.to_datetime() works but my dataframe is about 7.5 million rows so it is very slow.

I can specify the format using strftime syntax to avoid auto format detection and (I assume) substantially speed up the conversion.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime('2013-04-27 08:27:30.000001540', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Gives me:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 540
```

If I chop off the last three characters of the timestamp this works perfectly. Seems like the elegant solution here is to determine the Python compatible strftime directive for nanoseconds. I tried %9N, %N, %9. Any ideas?

Comment: this works w/o specifying a format in 0.15.0

Comment: @Jeff, thanks. I assumed that specifying the format would be faster. I'll have to benchmark to see if that's actually true.

Comment: no the formats are almost always slower. you have a standard c-parsable format.

Comment: @Jeff In this case that is true, but still, assume you don't have a standard but with nanoseconds, not being able to specify that in the format string is a bit annoying I think.

Comment: use ``infer_datetime_format`` is best actually. Certain formats are fast parsable (e.g. ``%Y%m%d`` and 'standard' ones), others require pattern matching and are by definition slower. FYI. You should be able to specify it in the format string, you just don't need to. (I am not sure of the exact format though)